# How to get n successful operation results exactly from a flux?

Tags: java, project-reactor

There are `m` elements emitted by a flux, then I want to do an operation on each element one by one which returns a Mono and get `n` successful operation results. When I get `n` successful results, i want to stop the stream.

I can implement the above ability by the following code, but i don't want to use `block()`.

Can someone please help me solve the problem?

```java
List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);
return Flux.just(items)
       .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
       .flatMap(item -> {
         // do operation on the item
          if(operation().block()){
             counter.getAndAdd(1);
          }
        })
       .takeUntil(x -> counter.get() >= n)
       .then();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterWhen` to keep only successful items based on a `Mono<Boolean>` returned by the `operation` method. Then you can use `take` to limit how many of these successful items you need.

```java
Flux.fromIterable(items)
            .filterWhen(item -> operation(item))
            .take(n)
            .then();
```